# Jekyll not regenerating

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I've been experimenting with Jekyll, and I can't get Jekyll to regenerate file changes (jekyll --server --auto). I'm using Sass, but I can't even get it to work with normal css. I've tried plugins, I've tried pulling other people's repos and just using there code, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with the gem. An easy fix is:

```
gem uninstall directory_watcher
gem install directory_watcher -v 1.4.1
```

Here's a link for reference: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/970

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Changes I make only take effect after about a minute or so. During the uninstall found out that I already had version 1.4.1. Re-installed - no change.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this when I installed a sitemap plugin. Once I removed the plugin, the site started generating again.