# jekyll server on but not regenerating

Tags: git, powershell, github, rubygems, jekyll

I am in powershell and I command jekyll serve --watch.
It gives this output:

```
PS C:\Users\kyle\Programming\GitHub\AwesomeIncU> jekyll serve --watch
Configuration file: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU
       Destination: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU/_site
      Generating...
                    done.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled
```

When I just say jekyll serve it gives this:

```
 PS C:\Users\kyle\Programming\GitHub\AwesomeIncU> jekyll serve
Configuration file: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU
       Destination: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU/_site
      Generating...
                    done.
Configuration file: C:/Users/kyle/Programming/GitHub/AwesomeIncU/_config.yml
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

I would be fine with this without being able to watch it, but unfortunately it does not actually serve correctly.  It does not regenerate the files.  Only time regeneration actually happens is when I stop the server and the serve it again.

My versions are as follows:
jekyll: 2.0.3.
git: 1.9.2.
pip: 1.5.6.
python: 2.7. 
ruby: 1.9.3
And I am running on windows. 
I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995761/jekyll-not-regenerating) post and it did not work.

Comment: Could you please try installing Ruby 2.0.0? I had the same issue and for me, this solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem and fixed by just appending `--force_polling` at the end of `jekyll serve`, aka `jekyll serve --force_polling`.

For detail, please refer to this issue ['jekyll serve' generating done without server on](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2933).

Answer (score -1):

try clear your browsing data, like cookies or history. i had your problem just now and i do clear my browsing data, and jekyll regenerate fine.